# Increment a column yearly in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have the following schema for my database:

```
faculty(fid,fname,date of joining, salary, specialisation)
course(cid,cname,credits,semester, department)
teaches(fid,cid)
```

I want to implement the following:

> Increment the salary by 2000 of faculty after each year, starting salary may be 100000.

I was thinking of how to implement it as it is a trigger, but that's only on insertion (before/after), so how would I be able to implement this?

Please help

Comment: Are you using PHP, if yes then try to do it via cron job

Comment: You'll want to create a table of adjustments to make sure you don't perform them twice. There's nothing worse than a schema that has problems but no audit trail built into it. Do this by either recording their salary for a particular year as individual records, or by recording salary increases in a secondary table, keyed by faculty ID and year.

Comment: Running manually is ok if all employees joined at the same date and there will be no future employees ever getting into the DB table.  Use MySQL event and run it daily automatically. It works like a charm. Best feature ever in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

I would use MySQL event and schedule to run it daily (because different employees may have different dates of joining) at a predefined time of your choice using mysql scheduler (which is not enabled by default, you need to turn it on using event_scheduler=ON in the config file).

In the event, you can write a simple update SQL query that will check date of joining and if the current date is greater than the date of joining + one year, update the salary (`salary = salary + 2000`).  Now you may need another date field "`salary last updated`" and then in the update query you will check if the current time stamp is greater than last update in salary and one year has not elapsed since. If adding a new field is not possible and if the yearly increments are consistent and same for everybody, you may find out if an increment has already been applied this year by say `(current salary- base year salary)/increment` amount to see how many increments have been applied in current year - date of joining year.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html for more on MySQL scheduled events.

After enabling event scheduler, you can add an event like this

```
CREATE EVENT `UpdateSalaryEvent` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-05-15 03:00:00' 
DO BEGIN
    -- event body   YOUR SALARY UPDATE SQL GOES HERE
END;
```

Comment: Its very easy, just put event_scheduler =ON in .cnf file and restart the server.  If you don't want to restart the server immediately, you may run  set glabal event_scheduler=ON in workbench.  After that all you have to do is to create an event and add one SQL statement there.